# Infinite loop occurs while using ref by passing index prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```
 const container = useCallback((node: any) => {
    console.log(node);
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      {reports.map((report, i) => (
        <Resizer ref={container} key={i}>
          {report}
        </Resizer>
      ))}
    </>
  );
```

--> this works well but with no index

```
 const container = useCallback((node: any, index: number) => {
    console.log(index, node);
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      {reports.map((report, i) => (
        <Resizer ref={(node) => container(node, i)} key={i}>
          {report}
        </Resizer>
      ))}
    </>
  );
```

--> infinite loop occurs!!

Is there a reason why second code occurs infinite loop?

Adding global index variable won't be the method

Answer (score 0):

In the first instance you are passing function directly as the `ref`, and so it is only created once.

But in second case a new instance of the function is created on every render, and so the function that is passed to the ref will have a different reference each time which will re-render every time.

You can try passing index as an dependency to the useCallback hook, so that it is only recreated when the index value changes.

```
 const container = useCallback((node: any, index: number) => {
                       console.log(index, node);
                   }, [index]);
```